# Constraining an F# generic function to a union type?

Tags: generics, f#, discriminated-union

As per the title, is there any way to constrain an F# generic function to a union type? So far I am using:

```
let toDomain<'T> external: 'T option =
    assert FSharpType.IsUnion(typeof<'T>)
    ...
```

Which fails at runtime with a System.ArgumentException if I attempt to use a non-union, but I would prefer the check earlier.

Comment: You've been asking a couple of questions here that seem to push the envelope of the F# type system. Have you considered a more idiomatic approach? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @MarkSeemann - We have a lot of mapping "glue" code between our established C# code base and newer F#. Our actual F# is functional but at the moment mapping C# types involves a lot of repeated code which is impacting our scalability so I've been looking at writing something more generic.

Comment: In [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28538106/126014) you write that you want to be able to write `let testThings = toDomain<MyModule.MappedThings> doExternalThings`. How is that better that `let testThings = MyModule.MappedThings doExternalThings`? The native F# syntax is shorter that the function call you're after, and type-safe...

Comment: I can see your point. My real-world example is quite a bit more complicated, at the time I want to perform the mapping, I have an obj and so need to reflect over my union 'T to see which case takes that obj type. This has resulted in a lot of repeated mapping code everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

If you peek at the [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/reflect.fs#L897) of `IsUnion` and follow the code a bit, it boils down to checking for the presence of the attribute/argument `[<CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.SumType)>]`.

For now there is no support for purely attribute-based constraints, either in F# or in .NET.